# Point of intersection $g(x)=e^{-x^2/c}$ and curve $f(x)=x^2+4x+4$.But using derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives

I am trying to find (point of touch) of two function

1.$g(x)=e^{-x^2/c}$ (gaussian)

2.$f(x)=x^2+4x+4$ (quadratic)

I approached by equating tangents of both equation to equal.Thus
I equated following equation..::..

$ 2x+4=-2x^3/c\cdot e^{-x^2/c}$

But i caught up with lograthmic equation which goes like this..

$ \ln((2x^3/c)+2x+4)=-x^3/c$

I dont know how shall i proceed from here..
Thank You

Comment: derivative is tangent to curve..so when they are equal it means they are touching each other..Thats why i did so.My target is to common point which lies in both tangent equation of curves. in simple...

Comment: "Point of touch" is a bit confusing. It could mean intersection or tangency (which I guess is what you mean).

Comment: If you say point of touch everyone will assume that you want to find the $x$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Ok buddy..I have seen the plots..its intersecting..for ease lets say point of intersection.But aren't the touching..

Comment: you can say i want to find $g(x)=f(x)$ but using derivative...

Comment: simple you can see..that if a function is defined as $f(x)=(a qudratic function)$ then a another function on x-axis defined by $axis(x)=0$..then if we equate for derivative for equality then we obtain  root of  $f(x)$ . Which satisfy for roots of equation if one and only one root is possible

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the equations

$f(x)=g(x)$ and $f'(x)=g'(x)$

lead to

$2c(x+2)=-2x(x+2)^2$.